# How to escape special characters in query string sent via JQuery ajax function?

Tags: jquery, django, post, escaping, query-string

I need to POST short messages to the server.  Sometimes they have special characters, like in this example:

```
&message=Joining a game of Commands & Colors: Ancients.
```

How do I escape special characters from a query string?

I'm using Django.  Here's the field I need to encode:

```
<textarea class="text-area" id="message" name="message" rows="3" cols="30">
   Joining a game of {{ game.name }}.
</textarea>
```

UPDATE:  I realize that the POST is going through JQuery's ajax function:

```
  $("#checkin-button").click(function() { 
          var mid = $("input#mid").val();
          var message = $("textarea#message").val();
          var facebook = $('input#facebook').is(':checked');
          var name = $("input#name").val();
          var bgg_id = $("input#bgg-id").val();
          var thumbnail = $("input#thumbnail").val();
          var dataString = 'mid='+mid+'&message='+message+'&facebook='+facebook+'&name='+name+'&bgg_id='+bgg_id+'&thumbnail='+thumbnail;  
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/game-checkin",  
      data: dataString,
```

So I'm not passing that correctly (urlencoded) right?

UPDATE: after realizing the issue was with JQuery, I was able to fix it by replacing the data variable assignment with:

```
    data: {"mid": mid, "message": message, "facebook": facebook, 
"name": name, "bgg_id": bgg_id, "thumbnail": thumbnail}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Python](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode):

```
>>> urllib.urlencode({'message': 'Joining a game of Commands & Colors: Ancients.'})
'message=Joining+a+game+of+Commands+%26+Colors%3A+Ancients.'
```

[Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode):

```
message={{ message|urlencode }}
```

Comment: Thanks, so how would I encode the value in my field above?  Just updated the post with my template code.

Comment: No it's not.  According to Firebug it's the raw string, and when I print it out from the server, it's truncated to "Joining a game of Commands".

Comment: Updated the original post.  I'm sending through JQuery - that must be the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
import urllib;
urllib.urlencode("string");
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

So : becomes %3A
BTW...most modern browsers do this automatically.